# Performance impact of retrieving a element from a List

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

In my Code I maintain a data heap whose basic component is a Map.The Map would be somewhat like:

```
Key -TableName\Field\Attribute1
Value-3
```

I used to retrieve my value by :

```
map.get(key)
```

Now I required a List instead value.The Map would be somewhat like:

```
Key -TableName\Field\Attribute1
Value-[3,30,300]
```

Now I need to retrieve my value by :

```
map.get(key).get(index)
```

How much would this change affect the performance of my Code?

Comment: that totally depends on what kind of list you use. An ArrayList can be accessed in constant time, as well as a HashMap (I think) so if you use the right data-structures it should not affect time (speaking about complexity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exist single answer to your question, its broad and you can consider all the answers. Basically, you need to understand time complexity of HashMap and ArrayList and that would give you an idea on how your code is going to perform.

The following image ([source](http://infotechgems.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html)) gives you an idea of time complexity O(1), O(log n), O(n), ...

[image]

Now Hashmap have the following time complexity (see [here](http://coding-geek.com/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java/) for more details on how hash map work in java)

```
get() and put() - usually O(1) but O(n) worst case scenario
```

Best case scenario, get() and put() have O(1) cost in time complexity. If you have a inefficient hash function then the data is not distributed correctly across buckets hence, you might end with slow get() and put() methods. An efficient hash function distributes the data in all buckets in a balanced manner, if there is no balance between the buckets containing entries then you will have slower get() and put(). See [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/lectures/lec21.html) and [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/hash_function_guidelines.shtml) for details on how to design your hash function.

Note the HashMap [performance improvement in Java 8](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/04/hashmap-performance-improvements-in.html).

ArrayList on the other hand have the following time complexity:

```
add() - O(1)
remove() - O(n)
get() - O(1)
contains() - O(n) (traversal)
```

Basically you perform O(1) (O (n) worst case) to get the list and then you are doing another O(1) to get the item from list. So both operations are in constant time provided your hash function is efficient.

As mentioned in other answers, there are a variety of other ways to improve the performance of your code by using array instead of list if possible, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is nearly impossible to tell the impact on performance of code without seeing any code, performance overhead of storing a list instead of storing a single `Integer` could be relatively small: in both cases you would end up paying for unboxing the `int` from `Integer` and for the has look-up on the key, so the only additional operation is the `get(index)` on the list.

- If the list inside the map is an `ArrayList`, the operation is fast O(1) lookup
- If the list inside the map is a `LinkedList`, the operation is O(n), where `n` is the number of elements on the individual list.

It's worth noting that if the list has a small fixed size (say, three or four elements, as shown in your example) you may be better off defining a custom class for the four elements, and make these elements `int`s. This would save memory and reduce the overhead.

For lists of fixed large size you may want to consider `int[]` arrays, because they let you avoid boxing for a reduction in memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

best case for Lookup of hashmap will be O(1) and worst case will depend on hash collision and JDK8 has some nice improvement to handle that scenario, so from map perspective lookup cost will be same no matter if you put single value or list of values associated to key.

cost for look up on list of value by index depends on type of list you are using , if it is array based(i.e ArrayList) then it is constant but it is linked list then cost is O(N).

So it is really choosing why type of list you want to put depending on your performance goal.